# 32-bit OS on a 64 bit processor

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, cpu

I have a laptop with a 64-bit processor, but by accident i installed the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04. i can always back my data up, and re-install Ubuntu, but i want to know if using 32-bit will be slower on a 64-bit processor, than a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit processor. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Like @neon_overload said, almost none-no difference. Usually with 32 bit, it's easier to install software, such as Skype etc. But nowadays, it's pretty easy. BTW, 64 bit is more powerful and if you can have it, why not?

Benefits of 64 bit:

- 16 general purpose registers instead of 8
- Additional SSE registers
- A no execute (NX) bit to prevent buffer overrun attacks
- More powerful compared to 32 bit
- Higher C integer limit

Benefits of 32 bit:

- Easier install of software sometimes
- Faster if low on RAM (512 MB - 1 GB)

Answer (score 0):

Running 32 bit Ubuntu will only be marginally slower than running 64 bit Ubuntu. Some software benefits more from the new instructions in x86_64 than other software. Overall the speed difference will be negligible.

A more important issue is the memory limit of around 3GB for the system and a per process limit of 2GB even if you have more RAM installed. If you have no more than 2GB RAM on the machine the drawback of 32 bit Ubuntu will be small but if running with more RAM the drawback is that you won't be able to use all that RAM which is somewhat more severe a drawback.

Conversely when you are severely limited in RAM, for instance you have less than 512MB, then 32 bit can theoretically gave some benefits in that compiled 32 bit code takes up a little less memory than compiled 64 bit code. However the difference is small and increasing system RAM if possible is a much better solution than the small percentage of benefit you'd get from smaller code size of 32 bit code.